# Trying to find efficient ways to remove headers in fasta files

Tags: python, sequence, biopython, fasta

I wrote an ugly code which removes the fasta header and creates a variable with the protein sequence as a string. How could I do this more efficient? Is there a good way how to do this in biopython?

```
f = open('protein1.fasta', 'r')
raw_samples = f.readlines()
f.close()

samples = ''

for elem in raw_samples:
    if elem[0] == '>':
        raw_samples = elem[1:].rstrip()
    else:
        samples += elem.rstrip()

print samples
```

Comment: You're overwriting `raw_samples` while iterating over it, and you're setting it to a a single element instead of maintaining all the samples. Seems like you're not getting what you think you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like

```
sequences = []
with open('protein1.fasta', 'r') as fin:
    sequence = ''
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            sequences.append(sequence)
            sequence = ''
        else:
            sequence += line.strip()
```

With biopython, you could do

```
from Bio import AlignIO
alignment = AlignIO.read(open('protein1.fasta'), 'fasta')
sequences = [record.seq for record in alignment]
```

**Edit**: Actually what I've been doing most often, when my sequences have no linebreaks in them, is something like:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
sequences = []
with open('protein1.fasta', 'r') as fin:
    for header, seq in izip_longest(*[fin]*2):
        sequences.append(seq)
```

The important thing here is the `zip(*[fin]*2)` which zips the file iterator `fin` with itself (`[fin]*2 == [fin, fin]`).  Due to a.) the way the file iterators work and b.) that we're zipping it with itself, you can think of the `zip` operation as

```
yield (fin.next(), fin.next())
```

which yield two lines at a time, which fits nicely with fasta files where sequences don't have line breaks.

Comment: Or use SeqIO (and SeqIO.parse) instead of AlignIO (and AlignIO.read), if this isn't an alignment

Answer (score 0):

An example using biopython and a dictionary to store the variable, in case accessing via a dictionary is advantageous in your situation:

```
dct = {}
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(open(infile.fasta), "fasta"):
    try:
        dct['samples'].append(str(seq_record.seq).upper())
    except:
        dct['samples'] = str(seq_record.seq).upper()
```

Many tools introduce line-wrapping in fasta files, so for robustness, I would use biopython to import the file. 
@wflynny biopython + list comprehension solution is probably more efficient, but 
I would use the dictionary method if you want to have multiple variables, each linked to a sequence(s)